# Pregunta sobre Liquid: ¿deberia poner el mensaje de texto dentro del if y del else?

Tags: liquid

```
{% assign COUNTRY_CODE = "57" %} 
{% assign NORMAL_LEN = 12 %}
{% assign msisdn_len = custom_attribute.${msisdn} | size %} 
{% assign prefix = custom_attribute.${msisdn} | slice:0,2 %}
{%  if prefix != COUNTRY_CODE and msisdn_len < NORMAL_LEN %} 
    {% assign msisdn = custom_attribute.${msisdn} | prepend: COUNTRY_CODE %} 
{% else%} 
    {% assign msisdn = custom_attribute.${msisdn} %} 
{% endif %} 
    {%capture text%}
        Ya activaste Amazon Prime Video con 3 meses de cortesia en tu plan pospago Tigo. Conoce mas sobre tu servicio en b.tigo.com/amazon. Aplican TyC{%endcapture%}https://prod.api.tigo.com/v1/tigo/mobile/kannel/sendsms?from=Tigo&to={{custom_attribute.${msisdn}}}&text={{text | url_encode}}
```

Comment: Si deberías manejar mensajes en los if y else.

Comment: Gracias Stack Overflow, el codigo resulto estar correcto, disculpen las molestias. :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer, puedes imprimir el mensaje dentro del if o capturar las variables dentro de la misma para despues del if las puedas usar

Ejemplo:

```
{% if block.settings.image != blank %}
  <img class="Nature-icon Icon-height-{{ forloop.index0 }}" src="{{ block.settings.image | img_url: 'master' }}" alt="{{ block.settings.image.alt }}">
{% else %}
  {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
{% endif %}
```